# Add the same geometry more than once in the scene?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to reproduce a flower on Three.js, as exercise to learn how to transformations.

Here's the code where i create the stamen, the stam and the petals. I would like the petals to appear more than once from the same Petal mesh, but the ending result is only one petal (rotated).

```
            // stamen
            var stamen_geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.7,32,32);
            var stamen_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00fff0 } );
            stamen = new THREE.Mesh( stamen_geometry, stamen_material );
            stamen.position.set(0,2,0);
            scene.add( stamen );

            // stem
            var stem_geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0.3, 0.3, 3);
            var stem_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
            stem = new THREE.Mesh( stem_geometry, stem_material );
            scene.add( stem );

            var pivot = new THREE.Object3D();           

            //petal
            var petal_geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0, 0.3, 3);
            var petal_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
            petal = new THREE.Mesh( petal_geometry, petal_material );
            petal.rotation.z = 90 * Math.PI/180;
            petal.position.set(1.5,2,0);
            pivot.add( petal );
            
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                pivot.rotation.y = i*45*Math.PI/180;
                scene.add (pivot);
            }
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> scene.add (pivot);

You have to create an instance of `THREE.Mesh` for each petal. Right now, you add the same 3D object to the scene over and over again.

Simplified code:

```js
var petal_geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0, 0.3, 3);
var petal_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var petal = new THREE.Mesh(petal_geometry, petal_material);
    petal.rotation.y = i*45*Math.PI/180;
    scene.add(petal);
}
```